# In an ordered field, $a< ar + (1-r)b< b$ whenever $a<b$ and $0<r<1$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, ordered-fields

I am stuck on problem 9 from Berberian- A First Course in Real Analysis which deals with inequalites in an ordered field.

Problem:
Show that in an ordered field, $a< ar + (1-r)b< b$ whenever $a<b$ and $0<r<1$.

Proof Attempt:
Suppose $a<b$ and $0<r<1$. By multiplying $0<r<1$ by $a$ we have $0<ra<a$. By adding $-1$ to $0<r<1$ and then multiplying by $b$, we have $-b<(r-1)b<0$ or equivalently $b>(1-r)b>0$.

I am unsure how to manipulate the inequalites to proceed furthur. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Please add the question itself to the body of your question.

Comment: Hint: if $a<b$ and $0<r<1$ then $ar<br$ and $0<1-r$ so $(1-r)a<(1-r)b$.

Comment: A good way to approach a question like this is to take the inequality you want to prove - say $a < ar + (1 - r)b$ - and manipulate it using invertible steps until it is in a simpler form - in this case, of the form $0 < (\dotsb)(\dotsb)$ with two positive factors. Then write down the proof properly going in the right direction to check that your argument works!